# How to pass return value of a method as a input to other method

Tags: scala

```
def methodA(testvalue1 : String) : String={
  c=a+b
  return c
}

def methodB(testvalue2:String ) :String={
  //here I want to use value returned by methodA, how could I do that ?
}
```

I want to use return value `c` in `methodB`.

Comment: To get a value returned by `methodA()` you need to call `methodA()` and save the value it returns.

Comment: You could do something like `methodB(methodA(myValue))`

Answer (score 2):

[Function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)) is the technical term for your question.

Given

```
def methodA(s: String): String = {
  s + ", hello "
}

def methodB(s: String): String = {
  s + " world!"
}
```

all the following function compositions evaluate to the same value

```
val a = methodA("Shyam")
methodB(a)

methodB(methodA("Shyam"))

(methodA _ andThen methodB)("Shyam")

(methodB _ compose methodA)("Shyam")
```

namely

```
Shyam, hello  world!
```